# Locate user's region w/o asking his exact location

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

How can I locate the user's region without asking his permission for exact location (W3C Geolocation API)?

For example [mapbox's editor](https://www.mapbox.com/editor/#app) locates you (at least me) around the city I live (zoom level 9). That's what I want to do with each user.

How can I do the same?

Answer (score 0):

MapBox is doing this with IP address geolocation. An example of a service built around such technology is http://geoiptool.com